# React Native Refresh Control Custom Animation

Tags: react-native

> **Please check the video to understand.**https://youtube.com/shorts/JKQxK9tTDvM
>
> RED: HEADER, BLUE DOT: A View or Icon, GREY: Item inside FlatList,
> Refresh Control Height: Space between header and first item.

I want when pull-to-refresh FlatList the Blue dot move(Animated translateX) right depending on how much pull with min translateX=0 and max translateX = WINDOWS_WIDTH-BLUE_DOT_WIDTH (Middle of Header).

min translateX=0 is the X position before pull.

When start pull Blue dot move right.

When Refresh Control Height=0 --> BLUE dot position translateX=0,

When Refresh Control Height=MAX --> BLUE dot position translateX=MIDDLE and start refreshing.

When translateX=MIDDLE the means that Refresh Control get the height to start refresh and the blue dote start Loading

**After Loading**...the blue dot stop refresh and move left depending of Refresh Control Height.

When Refresh Control Height=MAX --> BLUE dot position translateX=MIDDLE,

When Refresh Control Height=0 --> BLUE dot position translateX=0,

> DRAFT CODE:
> https://snack.expo.dev/@stefanosalexandrou/authentic-watermelon